# Locate words in binary image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'd like to figure out a method for finding bounding boxes of words or a pair of words in binary image. The image itself looks like this: (bounding boxes I need are marked by blue rectangles).

[image]

Image is free of any other objects. I'm thinking about some form of connected component analysis, like detecting single letters first, then "drawing" their bounding boxes on another `Mat` object in such a way that neighbouring letters connect. There is a useful information I'd like to utilize - word or a pair of words forms a horizontal line, which is an information that could be used to separate "Hello there" and "abcdf" - I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: What about a OCR library like tesseract?

Comment: I'm interested in bounding boxes, exact text location, not text recognition.

Comment: Ok. I would start with a single contour and a simple heuristic whether to add another contour to the bounding rect or not. Maybe I'll find the time to test an implementation tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

1. Contour the image.
2. Pick contours with a suitable area and width/height to be letters - get coords of centers.
3. From list of centers decide how far apart 2 centers can be to be adjacent letters
   rather than a gap.
4. Group these contours into a word and take their
   bounding box

Opencv has clustering, contour area and bounding box funcs if you don't want to do it yourself

Comment: @karlphilip I assumed this was a hw question, otherwise the answer is - use tesseract. Nice to hear from you, I've been insanely busy at work for a few months so haven't posted much.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do OX-dilation using window size N, where N is approximate 1..2 size of letter width, then you will have black filled "boxes".
2. Find contours ( see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html ).
3. Find rectangles and correct its with (minus approx 1 size of letter width) due to dilation width enlargement.

Comment: What do you mean by OX dilation? A structuring element with only one row?

Comment: Yes, I mean 1D-structuring element. Sure you can use 2D structuring element too, but 1D is faster and enough for this task.

Comment: Please notice that "Hello there" and "abcdf" are so close to each other that enlargement will actually merge two rectangles. So instead of having two separate rectangles I'll have one. This is the problem I was having with the method I used (similar to yours).

Comment: No problem, just use OY dilation of the size M=~0.5..1*N (N mentioned above) and then OY erosion of size ~1.5..2*M before OX dilation - it will shrink vertical size of strings to its ~center line so OX-dilated lines("boxes) will have no intersection. Sure you will have to find appropriate parameters for this morphology steps to meet you line shift and letter size. You will always have threshold for horizontal gaps when it will be recognized as one phrase and for vertical word shift when it will be "recognized" as the same line.

Comment: Why I need OY dilation first? Isn't it enough to perform OY erosion you mentioned and then points 1., 2. and 3.?

Comment: For some window size morphology parameters you may avoid using OY dilation, but you'd better use it to prevent some letters like S or Z from disappearing. Just comment this dilation function call and check it -- it will takes 10 seconds only. My approach is flexible enough, very simple for understanding and fast for [GPU]computing.